# Forge DA4I and Vault

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Is there a way that I can integrate DA4I with Autodesk Vault ? I want to use a numbering scheme for the new parts/drawings that are generated in Forge. This numbering scheme is managed inside Vault and depends on the type of document.
I also want the newly generated parts to get checked-in into vault, including the relationships between parts and assemblies as if I pressed the check-in button in Inventor
Is there a way to get this done ? I thought that Autodesk was working on such a solution but can't find any info.

TIA
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO this is not possible directly. DA4I works in sandboxed (absolutely independent) environment. You are not able to communicate outside.

You can only reserve some numbers from Vault naming scheme and send them as parameter to the WorkItem. Then you can handle files before save and set them file name from given file names.